# How to get the index of an parent scope array/ng-repeat inside child ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am building a table and I have two `ng-repeat` for my table.

My question is if it's possible the child of the `ng-repeat` can get the parent `ng-repeat`'s index. For example:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="company in companies">
        <td ng-repeat="product in company">
            company # = {{the company index}} and product {{$index}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am not sure how to add the company index under the td `ng-repeat`. Is there a way to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly where [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) comes into picture, to alias special properties of ng-repeat, ex: `ng-init="companyIdx=$index"`. So each child scope created by company `ng-repeat` will have this `companyIdx` property.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="company in companies" ng-init="companyIdx=$index">
        <td ng-repeat="product in company">
            company # = {{companyIdx}} and product {{$index}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Using a `$parent` is fine but it you have any other directive that creates a child scope in between them, eg:- `ng-if`, another `ng-repeat` etc.. you will have to go crazy doing `$parent.$parent....`. Aliasing with `ng-init` makes it clean and more readable and maintainable as well.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, use `$parent`

```
company # = {{$parent.$index}} and product {{$index}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `$parent` can get you the parent scope's original array.  From there, the array `indexOf()` function will get you the index of the element with respect to its array.  In your code it looks like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="company in companies">
    <td ng-repeat="product in company">
        company # = {{$parent.companies.indexOf(company)}} and product {{$index}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Or just, `$parent.$index`